# jQuery - Kendo UI checkbox control

Tags: jquery, checkbox, kendo-ui

I've got this Kendo UI checkbox on a data grid header and when this is ticked,
all checkboxes on grid rows will need to be ticked as well and vice versa.

The tricky part is to make it listen to each grid row state so that
when any row changes its checkbox state, the grid header should be notified by this change
and change its state automatically because all rows are no longer checked/unchecked.

I've gone this far and finding it hard to take it further.
[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/uduvex/1/edit)

Would appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

What about following approach, would that work for you ?

```
var $grid = $('#grid');
var grid = $grid.kendoGrid().data('kendoGrid');
var rowCount = 2;

$('.parentCheckbox').click(function () {
     $('.childCheckbox').prop('checked',this.checked);
});

$('.childCheckbox').click(function () {
    var checkeBoxesCount = $grid.find('input:checked').size();
    $('.parentCheckbox').prop('checked',checkeBoxesCount == rowCount);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XsAZa/6/

Comment: @bobby_d_ Thanks for your input. I tried this but bulk tick/untick doesn't happen. [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/OVACuFi/1/edit)

Comment: @SeongLee the bulk works fine. The count behaves bit weird (I will post full solution later) : http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/XsAZa/5/

Comment: @Bobby_D_ Hi, have you had a chance to look into the count? I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have updated my answer, only difference is the selector searching for checked checkboxes. This approach will work as soon as you know how many records do you have.